# how to search in sub item array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, search

My array is this and I want that searching on field [Required skills] that have comma ,

How to search and match 100% input word with field [Required skills] ?

For example input is : ['fresh','ntro','very speed']

And should be search and return this item id I mean is id 1 and 2: [Required skills] => fresh , very speed,nitro

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [CAR title] => BMW
            [speed level] => high
            [Country] => DE
            [City] => Berlin
            [price] => 747500
            [Currency] => usd
            [Required skills] => fresh , very speed,nitro , glass 2 wall
            [size] => 4m
          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [CAR title] =>Benz
            [speed level] => high
            [Country] => DE
            [City] => Berlin
            [price] => 747500
            [Currency] => usd
            [Required skills] => fresh , very speed,nitro , glass 2 wall
            [size] => 4m
        )
```

My code is but not work please help me for solve this :

```
function searchSkills($array, $skill)
{
    $sumArray = array();

foreach ($array as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
     
       if($id =='Required skills' && strpos($value, $skill) !== false)
        {
              
              $sumArray[] = $value; 
        }
      
  }
}
return $sumArray;

}

$all = [];
$arr = [];
$all = searchSkills($array,'PHP');
$allinput = ['PHP','Symfony','JavaScript'];
for ($i =0; $i<count($all) ; $i++) {
   for ($j = 0; $j<count($allinput) ; $j++) { 
       if($all[$i] == $allinput[$j]){
          $mr = explode(',',$all[$i]);
           for ($k = 0; $k<count($mr) ; $k++) { 

            if( $allinput[$j] == $mr[$k]){
                $arr[] = $mr[$k];
            }
           }
         
       }
    
   }
}
```

Comment: Are the skills always in the same order `PHP, javascript ,golang, Unit-testing, SOLID` or could it start with SOLID and still be a "match"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I loop through the input and match against the required skills.
I first assume we get a match (true), but if one fails I set to false and move on.

If all the input match then match is still true so add the subarray to the result array.

```
$input = ['php','javascript','golang'];

foreach($arr as $sub){
    $match = true;
    foreach($input as $val){
        if(stripos($sub['Required skills'], $val) === false){
            $match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($match) $res[] = $sub;
}

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/SN2HD

And, next time... Please use var_export when you want to share arrays.

Comment: stripos($sub['Required skills'], $val) === false)  please say to me for what? and what thing return to me?

Comment: Strpos is search for string in haystack. str**I**pos is case insensitive meaning it will match PHP with php